# What makes `while` loop in Ruby faster than others?

Tags: ruby

I am using this code:

```
require 'benchmark'

LOOPS = 100_000_000

def while_loop
        i = 0
        while i < LOOPS do i += 1 end
end


def times_loop
        i = 0
        LOOPS.times { i += 1 }
end

Benchmark.benchmark do |b|
        b.report('while') { while_loop }
        b.report('times') { times_loop }
end
```

The output is (Ruby 2.6.0):

```
while  2.419529   0.000000   2.419529 (  2.426470)
times  7.225500   0.005673   7.231173 (  7.252794)
```

Why is `while` loop faster than others?

Comment: `LOOPS.times` creates an enumerator (`=> #<Enumerator: 100000000:times>`), so code must be executed to generate each element of the enumerator and  pass it to the block, even though the value is not used in the block calculation. I assume that is the reason for the difference in performance but I have no proof.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think it is worth noting that `(1..LOOPS).each` has similar performance to `LOOPS.times` and that `f = ->(_) { i += 1 }; (1..LOOPS).each(&f)` is slightly slower. I'd take a wild guess that block calling overhead is involved but I'd have to dig through the source to see how `while` is implemented.

Comment: I think that calling calling blocks without any arguments makes it slower...
Say for example, if you have yield, your code has to execute yield, even you have given no block argument...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the reasons is because `times` - it's a block. And it introduces new local variable scope. And it creates some sort of local variable, look:

`RubyVM::InstructionSequence.disasm(method(:times_loop))` returns

```
== disasm: #<ISeq:times_loop@1.rb:23 (23,0)-(26,3)>=====================
== catch table
| catch type: break  st: 0003 ed: 0014 sp: 0000 cont: 0014
== disasm: #<ISeq:block in times_loop@1.rb:25 (25,14)-(25,24)>==========
== catch table
| catch type: redo   st: 0001 ed: 0010 sp: 0000 cont: 0001
| catch type: next   st: 0001 ed: 0010 sp: 0000 cont: 0010
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000 nop                                                              (  25)[Bc]
0001 getlocal_OP__WC__1 i[Li]
0003 putobject_OP_INT2FIX_O_1_C_ 
0004 opt_plus         <callinfo!mid:+, argc:1, ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
0007 dup              
0008 setlocal_OP__WC__1 i
0010 leave            [Br]
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
local table (size: 1, argc: 0 [opts: 0, rest: -1, post: 0, block: -1, kw: -1@-1, kwrest: -1])
[ 1] i          
0000 putobject_OP_INT2FIX_O_0_C_                                      (  24)[LiCa]
0001 setlocal_OP__WC__0 i
0003 getinlinecache   10, <is:0>                                      (  25)[Li]
0006 getconstant      :LOOPS
0008 setinlinecache   <is:0>
0010 send             <callinfo!mid:times, argc:0>, <callcache>, block in times_loop
0014 leave                                                            (  26)[Re]
```

There are two local variables (`setlocal_OP__WC__1` and `setlocal_OP__WC__0`) in this case.

In opposite `while` use just one, `RubyVM::InstructionSequence.disasm(method(:while_loop))` returns

```
== disasm: #<ISeq:while_loop@1.rb:15 (15,0)-(20,3)>=====================
== catch table
| catch type: break  st: 0009 ed: 0032 sp: 0000 cont: 0032
| catch type: next   st: 0009 ed: 0032 sp: 0000 cont: 0006
| catch type: redo   st: 0009 ed: 0032 sp: 0000 cont: 0009
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
local table (size: 1, argc: 0 [opts: 0, rest: -1, post: 0, block: -1, kw: -1@-1, kwrest: -1])
[ 1] i          
0000 putobject_OP_INT2FIX_O_0_C_                                      (  16)[LiCa]
0001 setlocal_OP__WC__0 i
0003 jump             17                                              (  17)[Li]
0005 putnil           
0006 pop              
0007 jump             17
0009 getlocal_OP__WC__0 i                                             (  18)[Li]
0011 putobject_OP_INT2FIX_O_1_C_ 
0012 opt_plus         <callinfo!mid:+, argc:1, ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
0015 setlocal_OP__WC__0 i
0017 getlocal_OP__WC__0 i                                             (  17)
0019 getinlinecache   26, <is:0>
0022 getconstant      :LOOPS
0024 setinlinecache   <is:0>
0026 opt_lt           <callinfo!mid:<, argc:1, ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
0029 branchif         9
0031 putnil           
0032 leave                                                            (  20)[Re]
```

I think that the reason is not the only one.

But setting/getting new local variable slow down operation.

Comment: This depends *highly* on the implementation. For example, I am pretty sure that TruffleRuby is able to eliminate simple blocks completely. Also, any halfway competent Ruby implementation is able to eliminate local variables in cases like this.